# Add new field to mongoDB embeded Doc

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongo Document structure like this with **comments field as embedded doc**.

i want to add **"newField" : "something"**   to embedded comments field with **"cid" : "17426944"** :

**in java driver i tried :**

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();  // MongoDB query
BasicDBObject record = new BasicDBObject(); // MongoDB record
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject(); // fieldsToUpdate

query.put("comments.cid","17426944");
dbObject.put("comments.newField","something");
record.put("$set",dbObject );
mongoCtrl.updateCollection(query, record, false, true);  // mongoCtrl is my connection contrl
```

**problem here is :**

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: cannot use the part (comments of comments.newField) to traverse the element ({comments:[ ..........  ]})
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:100)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:142)
```

**sample doc :**

```
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("53abb8d17bfd6b92e2398d34"),
        "name" : "satish",
        "number": "1122112",
         "comments" : [
                {
                        "cid" : "17426944"                          
                },
                {
                        "cid" : "607395840"
                },
                {
                        "cid" : "393084416"
                }
        ]
}
```

**what i need :**

```
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("53abb8d17bfd6b92e2398d34"),
        "name" : "satish",
        "number": "1122112",
         "comments" : [
                {
                        "cid" : "17426944",
                         "newField" : "something"       
                },
                {
                        "cid" : "607395840"
                },
                {
                        "cid" : "393084416"
                }
        ]
}
```

Plz help me.Thanks vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close,  you just missed the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to match the position of the array found in your query portion:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();  // MongoDB query
BasicDBObject record = new BasicDBObject(); // MongoDB record
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject(); // fieldsToUpdate

query.put("comments.cid","17426944");
dbObject.put("comments.$.newField","something");
record.put("$set",dbObject );
mongoCtrl.updateCollection(query, record, false, true);
```